# How to get the individual object of a class?

Tags: python, django

I have a simple Django model defined as :

```
from django.db import models

LEVEL_CHOICES = (('beg', 'beginner'), ('ind', 'inter'), ('exp', 'expert'))

class scrape(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    # level= models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=LEVEL_CHOICES)
    time = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    
def __str__(self):
        return self.subject
```

I want my `views.py` to take the `subject` object as `scrape.subject.all()` which is  not working.

What is the way to take the value stored in the `subject` object and store in some variable so that I can perform some operations on it?

Comment: `scrapsFilteredBySubject = scrap.objects.filter(subject='my_subject')`?

Comment: Is subject another model?...

Comment: This is a pretty basic question which is well covered in the tutorial. For a start, how are you identifying which object you want?

Comment: @Sayse no its not another model.

Comment: Its unclear what you're actually trying to achieve, are you after a list of subjects? a list of scrap with a certain subject? something else?

Comment: scrap is my model,which contains a list of different subjects,level and time.subject can be any charfield like "physics" ,"computer science",i want to these list of subjects and store in a variable. @Sayse

Answer (score 2):

You can create a list of subjects by using [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

```
all_subjects = scrap.objects.values_list('subject', flat=True).distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some basic issues here

from django.db import models

```
LEVEL_CHOICES = (('beg', 'beginner'), ('ind', 'inter'), ('exp', 'expert'))

class Scrape(models.Model): # Classes should be uppercase
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    # level= models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=LEVEL_CHOICES)
    time = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self): # __unicode__ is more recommended if you're using python 2.x
        return self.subject
```

Now to get a list of your subjects, simply type:

```
mySubjects = Scrape.objects.all().values_list('subject', flat=True)
```

Comment: `__unicode__` is only "more recommended" if OP is using Python 2; there's no reason to assume that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are a bit on the wrong track. You can use the "all()" method only to fetch all db models, i.e. scraps (not subjects):

```
scraps = scrap.objects.all()
```

Getting all subjects could then be done in a second step:

```
subjects = [s.subject for s in scraps]
```

However, for performance reasons, you should do as as Sayse suggests above.

Comment: Thought I'd just say thanks for the mention.. but there is also a big difference in what is returned from the database which will affect performance drastically between using `all` and filtering

Comment: Possibly a big difference indeed sir! I wanted to stick as much as possible to the initial question, though. Anyway, I have edited my answer somewhat still.